# Sum values of dictionary if any character within key strings match

Tags: python, string, dictionary, substring

Imagine I have a dictionary with string keys and integer values, like:

```py
{'255': 8,
 '323': 1,
 '438': 1,
 '938': 2,
 '166': 1,
 '117': 10,
 '777': 2
}
```

I would like to create a new dictionary that contains the following information:

- keys = some new unique string (it can be anything)
- values = the **sum** of values from the above dictionary across all keys in the above dictionary that match **any** character within any of the matched keys.

In the above example, the result would look something like:

```py
{
 'group1' : 12, # Sum of key values for '255' (8), '323' (1), '438' (1), '938' (2)
 'group2' : 13  # Sum of key values for '166' (1), '117' (10), '777' (2)
}
```

To clarify, `group1` is created in the following way: `255` has a 2 which matches the 2 in `323`. Then the 3's in `323` also match the 3 in `438`. Finally, the 8 (or the 3) in `438` match the 8 (or 3) in `938`. So adding the values for these keys in the same order we get 8 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 12.

None of the above key values (`group1`) are merged with the remaining key values (for keys `166`, `117`, `777`; making up `group2`) because none of the characters from the `group1` keys match **any** of the characters in the `group2` keys.

Group2 is created in the same way by matching the 1 from `166` to the 1s in `117` and matching the 7 in `117` to the 7s in `777`.

Final notes:

- Only a single character needs to match at least one other single character between keys to be included in a "group"
- The order in which I just explained the above summation of values shouldn't matter, the result should work beginning from any pair within that group
- Key characters will always be digits
- Reminder that the keys of the output dictionary can be anything. I used `group1` and `group2` for convenience

**What is an efficient way to accomplish this?**

I thought about converting the key values into a `numpy` matrix where the rows represent a single key and the columns represent the values of each character. However, going down this path gets fairly complicated quickly and I'd rather avoid it if there is a better way.

Comment: There could be multiple possible solutions, right? Do you want the fewest number of groups or something? Otherwise you could just put each number in its own group?

Comment: Think they want the fewest number of groups. Writing an answer now.

Comment: There can't - it forms equivalence classes

Comment: Does the output only have two groups? Can it have more? If so, does the algorithm just keep iterating through the dictionary until it no longer as anymore numbers to process?

Comment: It can have `size of alphabet in all keys` groups, if every original key has unique characters

Comment: Could you explain 'efficient'? Andrej solution for sure is efficient in terms of code complexity, but if you need to improve time complexity, the find union is way go to.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the great answers. Yes, there should be the fewest number of groups possible. Any group that matches any character within any merged key should also be merged with so (as far as I can tell) there is only one correct answer.

Those interested in speed (what I meant by "efficient")... I tested Andrej and BrokenBenchmarks answers and Broken's is much faster (at least with my data). With my full data set, which contained > 1k of these examples that were much larger than the toy example, Andrej's example completed in ~8.9 seconds while Broken's completed in 0.07859 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to solve this problem. The `networkx` package provides an implementation, but [there's nothing stopping you from writing your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672022/17769815).

In essence, we maintain a collection of disjoint sets. Initially, every string belongs to its own disjoint set. For each pair of strings, if they have letters in common, we union the disjoint sets they belong to. This eventually gives us the groups that we're looking for.

From here, we use the `.to_sets()` method to get the groupings, and compute the desired sum:

```py
from networkx.utils.union_find import UnionFind

data = # dictionary in question, omitted for brevity
keys = list(data.keys())

uf = UnionFind(data.keys())

for outer_idx in range(len(keys)):
    for inner_idx in range(outer_idx + 1, len(keys)):
        if set(keys[outer_idx]) & set(keys[inner_idx]):
            uf.union(keys[outer_idx], keys[inner_idx])

result = {}
for idx, group in enumerate(uf.to_sets()):
    result[idx] = sum(data[key] for key in group)

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
{0: 12, 1: 13}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
d = {"255": 8, "323": 1, "438": 1, "938": 2, "166": 1, "117": 10, "777": 2}

keys, groups = list(d), {}
while keys:
    current = keys.pop()
    s_current = set(current)
    for k in groups:
        if s_current.intersection(k):
            groups[k].append(d[current])
            groups[current] = groups[k]
            break
    else:
        groups[current] = [d[current]]

out = {}
for k, v in groups.items():
    if id(v) not in out:
        out[id(v)] = sum(v)


print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{140318922050368: 13, 140318911221184: 12}
```

---

A little explanation:

We create a temporary dict `groups` where the keys are from original dictionary `d` and values are lists of values from the original dictionary which share a character with the key. Note: the lists are *shared* between the keys - total number of these lists are equal to total number of distinct groups.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @BrokenBenchmark's answer, but it is self-contained, and it also groups things by digit first, so there's no O(n^2) doubly-nested loop over all the strings.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_edges(strings):
    # group together common digits.
    by_digit = [[] for _ in range(10)]
    for i, s in enumerate(strings):
        for digit in map(int, s):
            by_digit[digit].append(i)

    # attach the first of each group to the rest.
    for digit_locations in by_digit:
        if digit_locations:
            x = digit_locations[0]
            for y in digit_locations[1:]:
                yield (x, y)

def union_find_groups(edges, n):
    parent = list(range(n))
    size = [1] * n

    def find(x):
        # find (path-splitting)
        while parent[x] != x:
            x, parent[x] = parent[x], parent[parent[x]]
        return x

    def union(x, y):
        x = find(x)
        y = find(y)
        if x == y:
            return
        # Union (by size)
        if size[x] < size[y]:
            x, y = y, x
        parent[y] = x
        size[x] += size[y]

    for x, y in edges:
        union(x, y)
    
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for x in range(n):
        result[find(x)].append(x)

    return result.values()

def main(input_data):
    strings = list(input_data.keys())
    index_groups = union_find_groups(get_edges(strings), len(strings))
    string_groups = [[strings[i] for i in group] for group in index_groups]
    print(string_groups)
    results = [sum(input_data[s] for s in group) for group in string_groups]
    return {f"group{i}": total for i, total in enumerate(results)}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = main({
        '255': 8,
        '323': 1,
        '438': 1,
        '938': 2,
        '166': 1,
        '117': 10,
        '777': 2
    })
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
[['255', '323', '438', '938'], ['166', '117', '777']]
{'group0': 12, 'group1': 13}
```